How to export png from openlayers map with mapbox-gl
I'm trying to switch from raster map to vector map in OpenLayers using mapbox-gl library, but for some reason map export to png is not working properly: map rendered with mapbox-gl is not visible on exported image. I see only other (geojson) layers, but not map.
With raster maps it works properly.
I'm using export as in example here:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html

If you are using a Mapbox-gl layer in OpenLayers as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-layer.html you will need to add
preserveDrawingBuffer: true,

to the mapboxgl.Map options to make it exportable.
Then to include it in the OpenLayers export you will need to add canvas.mapboxgl-canvas to the querySelectorAll list.
